# Submit button to insert HTML table row into DB table row

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, html-table

Does anyone know how I should design a query to insert a row of a HTML table, the content of which is from a table in my db, into another table in my db? I am struggling with relating the submit button to individual result rows.

html -

```
 <form id="order" name="form1" method="post" action="script/addOrder.php">
    <h3><a id="curry">Curry Dishes:</a></h3><img src="img/curry.jpg" >
        <table class="menu">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Dish Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Allergy Information</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
    <?php
            include "script/dbconn.php";

                $sql="SELECT `dish`.`dishName`, `category`.`categoryName`, `allergy`.`allergyName`, `dish`.`dishPrice`, `dish`.`dishDescription` FROM `dish` 
                INNER JOIN category ON dish.categoryID = category.categoryID
                INNER JOIN allergy ON dish.allergyID = allergy.allergyID
                WHERE `categoryName` LIKE 'Curry'
                ORDER BY dishName ASC";
                //-run  the query against the mysql query function
                $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                //-create  while loop and loop through result set
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    $Name=$row['dishName'];
                    $Desc=$row['dishDescription'];
                    $Price=$row['dishPrice'];
                    $Allergy=$row['allergyName'];

                    //-display the result of the array?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $Name;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $Desc;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $Allergy;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $Price;?></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Order"</td>
                    </tr>
            <?php }
    ?>
```

Comment: You need to learn the basics about html forms. In your code, the submit buttons won't send anything to the server except the submit buttons because you have no html fields, and unless you have a form tag around those, nothing will be sent when you click the buttons. Data to be submitted needs to be in html form elements such as input, select, etc.

Comment: There is a form around the table, I only pasted one section to avoid a wall of text as each section is the same only with a different SELECT query. Will add that above the PHP

Comment: You still don't have any fields, and your submit buttons will all have the same name, so you won't know which was clicked.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I think that's the main thing they're asking about, actually. And since it looks like the purpose of this thing is to add a dish to an order, they wouldn't really need to submit any of the other descriptive fields that are displayed, just an identifier for the dish.

Comment: Yeah, the content of the table is only for the user, none of the information will be required as with the dishID and orderID I can relate it all back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<button>` to submit with a value that indicates a specific row.

```
<button type="submit" name="dish" value="<?= $row['dishID'] ?>">Order</button>
```

I used 'dishID' although I didn't see it in your query. Based on the other tables, I assume it's there, so you'd just need to add it to the column list in your SELECT.

You'll be able to get the value of the clicked button from `$_POST['dish']` in `script/addOrder.php`. As far as the actual insert query, you'd need to be more specific about what you want it to do.

Comment: That was what I thought, I had done that but it was failing to return any results when I tested it with   

`code`$dishID = $_POST['dish'];
        
    $sql="SELECT dishName, dishPrice, dishID FROM dish WHERE dish.dishID = $dishID";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

Comment: Hm, that certainly looks like it should work. (Although there is an SQL injection vulnerability there.) I'd start with `var_dump($_POST)` to make sure you're getting the value properly.

Comment: Incidentally, you can format inline code in comments by enclosing it in backticks (`).

Comment: `$dishID = $_POST['dish'];
         var_dump($_POST);`

    `$sql="SELECT dishName, dishPrice, dishID FROM dish WHERE dish.dishID = '$dishID'";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);`

Gives me `array(2) { ["dish"]=> string(24) "" [""]=> string(0) "" } `

Adding a temp 'dishID' echo in the html table shows that the SELECT query in the initial block of code is working   

Giving the submit button an absolute value however, does work

Comment: Maybe you have an older PHP version where the shorthand echo isn't enabled? Do you see the ID in the page source? If not, try it with `<?php echo $row['dishID'] ?>` instead of `<?= $row['dishID'] ?>` in the button value.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks for your time!

Comment: Great! You're welcome. I'm happy to help with this because I'm very supportive of any attempts to provide curry. ;)